# Simplifying a quadratic expression involving addition and subtraction

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to understand how this distribution works or how the following two lines end up being equal. I tried working it out on paper but there is just something fundamental I am missing.

$$
(v_x − w_x)^2 + (v_y − w_y)^2 + (v_z − w_z)^2 − (v^2_x + v^2_y + v^2_z) − (w^2_x + w^2_y + w^2_z)
$$

$$
−2v_xw_x − 2v_yw_y − 2v_zw_z
$$

The best I could come up with is distributing the negative sign:

$$
(v_x − w_x)^2 + (v_y − w_y)^2 + (v_z − w_z)^2 − v^2_x - v^2_y - v^2_z − w^2_x - w^2_y - w^2_z
$$

This part is where I get stuck since I know that distributing the exponent across addition is wrong:

$$
(v_x − w_x)^2 \ne v^2_x - w^2_x
$$

I also notice that $v_x$ has been multiplied by $w_x$ some how to create $-2v_xw_x$. I just don't understand how this happened.

The context is an explanation in a book about 3D programming of how using the law of cosines on a dot product leads from $\|v\| \|w\| \cos\theta$ to the formula $v_xw_x + v_yw_y + v_zw_z$

Sorry for the really basic question.

Edit:

Ok I get it now:

$$
(a − b)^2 = a^2 − 2ab + b^2
$$
$$
(a - b)(a - b)
$$
$$
(a - b)a - (a - b)b
$$
$$
a^2 - ab - ab + b^2
$$
$$
a^2 - 2ab + b^2
$$

It's been a while :) thank you @Mortiz

Comment: Does $(a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$ help?

Comment: Ohh yes it does. Thank you! :)

Comment: You are very welcome!